# Commit related Git hooks not invoking

Tags: git, bash, githooks

Before anyone claims I didn't search enough for answers on this topic, let me clarify:

I have found MANY threads about this issue that were resolved, however; none of those answers worked for me.

I have already made sure that the user performing the commit has the proper permissions.

I have ensured the hook file itself is executable and does not end in .sample

I am not working in a bare repo, so commit related hooks SHOULD invoke.

I have tried committing in Git Bash, Git Commit tool, and even a third party GUI GitEye, all with the same results.

Post-commit and Pre-commit both fail whether I attempt to invoke them from the repo on my server as well as from a clone on my local machine.

The hook files themselves successfully execute and work as intended if I run them as bash/batch files.

Other hooks such as Update work fine, but nothing that invokes from git commit.

At this point, I've exhausted all possible issues that I can think of. Any help is appreciated, but please read what I've already attempted before carelessly directing me to a thread that suggests one of the aforementioned things. I'm hoping there is some obscure fix to this that some Git-savvy user can explain to me.

Comment: Is it a client side or server side hook?

Comment: Can you add links to the solutions you've already tried, so we know which ones would be repeats? Also, what is your actual question? It seems like it would be something along the lines of "How can I get this Git hook to invoke?", but you haven't expressly stated a question.

Comment: I believe both pre and post commit are client side hooks

Comment: I directly stated which things I've tried. If you'd really like me to, I can post the threads those solutions were found in, but I pretty much summed up that list of fixes (user permissions, file permissions, bare/non-bare repo, ending in .sample, etc)        My question should be pretty evident. "Why are these not invoking when everything in the documentation says they should be, and how do I make them invoke?"

Comment: You don't have a git alias for commit that uses `-n`/`--no-verify` or have that set in the config (if that's possible)? Show us `ls -l` on the hooks directory in your repo? (And the output from trying to commit something in that repo?) Can you show us the hooks themselves? Are they logging verbosely and obviously?

Comment: `update` is a server-side hook. `pre-commit` and `post-commit` are client-side hooks. You can't test both at the same time. Hooks are per-directory so having tested set one doesn't mean anything about the other ones. We need to *see* what you are dealing with (not just have you assert it to us) if you want us to be able to help you (even if that help is git magic).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7ykq4w   This shows the output of ls -l as well as the contents of my hook. I had more echos in the hooks previously, ensuring to myself that it was being execute by the proper user. It was.

Comment: Executing the hook directly as a bash script works, and successfully starts the Jenkins build. http://prntscr.com/7ykrf1  However, this does not seem to happen upon commit.

Comment: also, as for the git alias question, no I shouldn't have anything like that. This is a pretty fresh git install, and even if there were something like that, it would only be able to bypass pre-commit. I don't believe there is a parameter to bypass post-commit; at least not from what I remember from the documentation though. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm. In your git repository there are hook samples you can use them like this:

For example:

1) a simple hook (pre commit) that forbide commits with and prints a message.

```
$ git init
$ cp ./.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample ./.git/hooks/pre-commit
$ cat ./.git/hooks/pre-commit

#!/bin/sh
cat <<\EOF
    This is pre-commit hook
EOF
    exit 1

$ touch README
$ git add README 
$ git commit
    This is pre-commit hook
$ git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

2) a simple hook (post commit) that prints message after commits

```
$ rm -f ./.git/hooks/pre-commit
$ cat ./.git/hooks/post-commit 
#!/bin/sh
cat <<\EOF
    Good job!
EOF

$ git commit
    Good job!
[master (root-commit) b552b7f] README
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README

$ git log --oneline
b552b7f README
```

As you can see the hooks are just a bash scripts so you can customize it.

Comment: Did you read my question? I know how to make a git hook, and how it SHOULD work, the problem is that it isn't invoking. I can call my hooks manually as bash script over SSH, but they do not invoke when they should upon git commit.

Comment: As you can see my hooks work, so there might be a problem with rights or whatever, can you show us the hooks so we can try them ourselves?

Comment: It's not a permissions issue, of that I'm certain. I stated that in the question. I'm just attempting to curl an API url for Jenkins in post-commit. So you could simulate that with 
`#!/bin/bash 
curl http://google.com`

Comment: Do you want jenkins to build you project once you commit changes? Is jenkins installed on you local computer or where?

Comment: Jenkins is installed on the same server as git, and everything works entirely fine in Jenkins. The issue is Git Hooks though, as I can't get anything to work in post-commit or pre-commit; not even a simple echo.

Comment: Look at [this](http://pastebin.com/RZ19Us3h), curl works as well in a post-commit hook, BTW, I use git version 2.4.6

Comment: See, that doesn't happen for me. The hook never invokes, even though I'm doing identically what you are doing. I appear to be using Git 1.9.5, is there any reason that would be the cause?

Comment: Let me check it tomorrow, I don't have git for windows right now.

Comment: @MatthewThurber, take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/BW4Pre9x) for windows a post commit hook with curl works as well